How do ee.Image.reduce Neighborhood with ee.kernel.circle change the pixel size of an image
I am trying to apply a standard deviation kernel to a raster layer with NDVI values ​​obtained from Sentinel 2 using Google Earth Engine. When using ee.Kernel.circle and ee.image.reduceNeigborhood the resolution of the resulting raster layer differs from the original. Could someone explain to me how these algorithms work in ee?
kernel = ee.Kernel.circle(**{'radius': 30, 'units':'meters', 'normalize':False})

sd = i.reduceNeighborhood(**{'reducer':ee.Reducer.stdDev(), 'kernel':kernel}) 

With a 10 meter resolution raster layer I get a 1 meter resolution after applying ee.reduceNeigborhood
